# SHA2 - Why is it difficult (actually impossible without using brute-force) to recover the message if you have the Digest and the Key

Tags: encryption, hash, sha

I looked into the implementation of SHA2 in Python and it looks like it uses some default key for hashing. Once the key is known and the digest is known, is it possible to get the plain-text back? (pre-image attack without brute-force) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack

My intuition says NO as the block size (input size) is 512 bit and the output size is 256 bit. It means that to be a good hashing function (cryptographically) the function should be many to one function (non-invertible). {This is the exact opposite to the requirement of a block cipher where the function should be invertible (one to one).}

As far as I understood the requirement is to have random many-to-one function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible, even with Brute Force, to recover the plain text for a given hash because there are many texts that map to the same N-bit key (for any value of N).  That is, there are different messages that have the same digest value.

Comment: Yeah, but it's likely that only a few aren't completely garbled nonsense (which one can check for programmatically).

Comment: @arxanas Wrong, the term is call "entropy". If the hash has significantly less entropy than the message, then there could be (exponentially) many valid messages that hash to the same digest.

Comment: @Mysticial Let say i want to recover one such (which maps to given digest) plain text message. is it feasible to get it without brute-force? in other words what makes the SHA256 algorthim non invertible. If i have the code of SH256 (which is open source) why can't i write the inversion of it?

Comment: In general - no. There do exist some attacks against some hashing functions, which work under some/limited circumstances, but you'll likely need to understand a _lot_ of Math and Cryptograhy to get there. If there were an attack that worked reliably in a small fraction of the time on a particular hashing fuction, that function would be considered "broken", and not for use.

Comment: @David If you had infinite computation power (or you break the hash), you find that there are an infinite number of different messages that hash to the same digest. Of those, a subset of them could be valid coherent messages that make sense. But the trouble is that you won't know which is the correct one. That's entropy.

Comment: @Mystical, yes sure, in theory. However, some past hash functions had biases (or other problems) which made this not necessarily true, in practice. EDIT: meaning not needing infinite computational power, nor having infinite possible plaintexts.

Comment: @Mystical: "But the trouble is that you won't know which is the correct one" -> depends how you define correct or valid. Let say for my purposes any message with map to same digest is valid.  actually this is reasonable assumption as many of the online site just stores your hash digest in their database. so anything which maps to the digest is a valid password for any such auth system. so let say if i am interested in extracting any 1 valid message is enough

Comment: @David Yes, that's correct. I meant to say the "original" one that was used to produce the digest in the first place. But yes, you can theoretically use any password that produces the right digest to get past authentication. But if you were trying to extract a message from its cipher text (or its digest), entropy is what makes the [XOR cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)/[one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) unbreakable if done properly.

Comment: @Mystical SHA256 is not a cipher(although very similar in concept  to a cipher), First of all the key is not secret in SHA256. Atleast it is not necessary to specify the key in SHA256 python implementation (which means it is taking a default key), once the key is static (fixed) what makes this system irreversible?

Comment: Oooh, `@David` vs `@David-SkyMesh`... got confusing fast :-)